# Is there a way to trigger a completable without subscribing in rxjava?

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java3, rx-java-completable

I have a chain of completables, but when I need to execute the completables, I have to subscribe each of it seperately. Is this the normal way of using it?

Is there any examples where I could chain completables using one subscribe?

Comment: Use `concat` or `merge`.